# When to use HLS or DASH format for web application

Tags: reactjs, web, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I'm building a web application (reactjs) to share videos.
For each video I have a `HLS` and a `DASH` format generated (since HLS is not supported on every device).

I would like to have a server side browser detection and use the right format for each device (using a web player - for now I'm using `video.js`)

What I know for sure is that for each iOS device HLS should work (on Safari, Chrome and Firefix). Is this correct ?

I have searched for more details but I'm having trouble having a list with the format for the main browsers and OS (`Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Safari`, `Edge`, `MacOS`, `Android` and `Windows`).

Can anyone help me with that ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general HLS compatibility can be simplified as:

- Browsers with native HLS compatibility (iOS browsers, Safari, few others)
- Browsers with MediaSource Extensions support (https://www.caniuse.com/mediasource)

You'll note that when combining both of these aspects, HLS is supported on most browsers on most platforms.  If you are streaming video, it's the most compatible of technology options you have.

DASH has similar compatibility groups, but there are no current browsers that support DASH natively.  Instead, DASH is supported entirely via MediaSource Extensions.  This enables DASH to be more flexible to future changes.  The only thing blocking it is Apple's business practices.  Apple doesn't enable MediaSource Extensions on iOS, does not allow alternative browser engines on iOS, and therefore dictates the lowest common denominator format for the entire industry.